# Axler 6.9: Show that the following list is orthonormal.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal, trigonometric-integrals

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z_{+}}$ and show that the list below is an orthonormal list of vectors in $C[-\pi,\pi]$ in the vector space of real valued functions on $[-\pi,\pi]$ with the inner product given below.

Inner product, with $f,g$ as real-valued functions: $$<f,g>\ = \ \int_{\ -\pi}^{\pi} f(x)g(x)\ dx $$
Given list:
$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\frac{sin x}{\sqrt{\pi}},\frac{sin\ (2x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},..., \frac{sin\ (mx)}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{cos\ x}{\sqrt{\pi}}, \frac{cos\ (2x)}{\sqrt{\pi}},..., \frac{cos\ (mx)}{\sqrt{\pi}})$$

Here I have two questions:

1. What does $C[-\pi,\pi]$ mean? Does it $C$ denote continouos?
2. How does one go about proving this? (I guess that I can break it down to the following cases, $\forall i,j\ \mathbb{Z}_{+}$:)
   $$1. \ <sin\ (ix), sin(jx)>\\ 2. <sin\ (ix), cos(jx)> \\ 3. <cos\ (ix), cos(jx)>$$

I am unsure if I should show this via some fancy trig formula, induction or some other way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just do the integrations you suggested for the three different parts, 1, 2, and 3 as you suggested, and then use the trigonometric identities for products, you must automatically be able to do these integrations.

And yes, $C$ means continuous functions.